# How to read multiple integers from a file when there's a string in between them

Tags: c, string, integer, file-handling, fseek

I am trying to read multiples integers from a file using a loop. The problem I am facing is there's a string in between those integers. My goal is to find the last integer in the file
ex:- `123  hello 1253 world`
So in the above case, the last integer would be 1253.

````
int id;
p=fopen("o.txt","r");
while(!feof(p))
{
    fscanf(p,"%d",&id);
    fseek(p,13,SEEK_CUR);
} ```

   

I used `fseek()` to jump over the string. There were 13 characters from the last digit to the beginning of the next digit.
This does not work and I ended up in an infinite loop.
Can anyone help?
Thank you
````

Comment: Use `fgets` to read one line. Then use `strtok` to parse the string into tokens. Or use multiple `fscanf` format specifiers - one for each of the tokens.

Comment: Fyi, [`while(!feof(p))` is *wrong*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: You can read char by char with ...`%c`... then try to convert on int, if convert return true then save that number into a int variable, else, discard that char and read the next one, i would recomend `strtol` for conversions from chars to ints

Answer (score 1):

> My goal is to find the last integer in the file ex:- 123  hello 1253 world So in the above case, the last integer would be 1253.

`while(!feof(p))` --> [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

A *slow* solution: read the entire file.  Look for integers.  If the next input is not an integer, consume input as a character and toss it (test for EOF)

```
long long last = 0;
for (;;) {
  long long i; 
  // Try to read 1 integer
  if (fscanf(p, "%lld", &i)==1) {
    last = i;
  } else {
    // read and consume one character.
    if (fgetc(p) == EOF) break;
  }
}
printf("Last: %lld\n", last);
```

---

Other ideas, go to the end.  Repeated seek back until fail, or reading forward yields an integer.

Untested idea.  Not itself that efficient, but to give OP an idea.

```
long offset = 0;
while (fseek(p,--offset,SEEK_END) == 0) {
  long long last;
  if (fscanf(p, "%lld", &last)==1) {
    while (fseek(p, --offset, SEEK_END) == 0) {
      long long i;
      if (fscanf(p, "%lld", &i)==1) {
         last = i;
      }
    }
    printf("Last: %lld\n", last);
    break;
  }
}
```

Use of `ftell(), fseek()` is problematic with text files as an `fseek()` to any place other than the beginning  or relative to a previous  `ftell()` result is UB.  Consider opening with  `"rb"`.